# Configuring multiple authentication providers in conjunction with oauth2+jwt

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to configure my Spring Boot 2, OAuth2 with JWT Authorization Server, which needs to do the following:

1. take a username/password, build a CustomUserDetails object based on db data and salesforce data, and return a JWT token if authentication passes (this works)
2. take a refresh token and return a new JWT refresh and access token (this works)
3. (NEW) take a refresh token, check against the db for a stored token ID before returning a new JWT access + refresh token (this is the trouble spot) The point of this is to ensure only one device is logged in with the user's credentials at a time.

In order to do #3, I am trying to customize the `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` by giving it a custom `UserDetailsService`, and the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` bean needs to be passed both the customized `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` and the `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.

Assuming I am going in the right direction with that, here is my configuration code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    //implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken>
    @Autowired
    CustomPreauthenticatedUserDetailsService customPreauthenticatedUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui**","/webjars/**","/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token/revokeById/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().csrf().disable();
    }
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManager) throws Exception {
        authenticationManager.authenticationProvider(preauthAuthProvider());
        authenticationManager.authenticationProvider(dbAuthProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier(value = "authenticationManagerBean")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean(value="preAuthProvider")
    public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preauthAuthProvider() {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preauthAuthProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        LOGGER.info("Setting customPreauthenticatedUserDetailsService");
        preauthAuthProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(customPreauthenticatedUserDetailsService);
        return preauthAuthProvider;
    }

    @Bean(value="dbAuthProvider")
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider dbAuthProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider dbAuthProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        dbAuthProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        dbAuthProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return dbAuthProvider;
    }

}
```

On the `AuthorizationServerConfig` side:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Integer ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 300;
    private static final Integer REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24 * 60;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, CustomTokenEnhancer customTokenEnhancer, TokenStore tokenStore, JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter) {
        this.authenticationManagerBean = authenticationManagerBean;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.customTokenEnhancer = customTokenEnhancer;
        this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
        this.accessTokenConverter = accessTokenConverter;
    }

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private CustomTokenEnhancer customTokenEnhancer;
    private JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter;
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer authorizationServerSecurityConfigurer) {
        authorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clientDetailsServiceConfigurer) throws Exception {

        clientDetailsServiceConfigurer.inMemory().withClient("someclient")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("read", "write").accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
                .secret(this.passwordEncoder.encode("somepassword"));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(customTokenEnhancer, accessTokenConverter));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
            .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManagerBean);
    }
}
```

Upon start up of the app, the first sign of trouble I see is:

```
s.c.a.w.c.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$3 : No authenticationProviders and no parentAuthenticationManager defined. Returning null.
```

Oddly, that appears to be a lie, or it's talking about something else, because when I try to login with username and password - it works, and I get both my refresh and access tokens. The debugger shows that the `ProviderManager` has both my custom authentication provider classes and uses them for authentication.

However, when I try to retrieve a new token with the refresh token, the debugger shows that the app appears to be taking a different `ProviderManager` path - this `ProviderManager` only has `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` in its list, and that provider is NOT the one I configured. This `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` is trying to retrieve a `UserDetailsService` from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator`, and the result is an error:

```
2019-06-08 13:27:24.764 ERROR 8731 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: IllegalStateException, UserDetailsService is required.
```

So, what configuration step am I missing? Why does the refresh token call go elsewhere? Is it the `authenticationManagerBean` that I'm passing in the `AuthorizationServerConfig`?

Comment: Have you looked at `http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)`? This will prevent the same user from logging in on a 2nd device/session.

Comment: Are you talking about using spring-sessions? I'll look into that. 

I had started thinking along the lines of calling a revoke refresh token by username+client endpoint for every login, which means I'd have to override the default oauth2 authorization endpoint...

However, the next story I need to work on involves pre-auth from a partner, so I think I'll still need to figure out this wiring. Managing it by number of sessions will be complicated if I have to somehow exclude partner pre-auth in that session count.

Comment: No, I'm not referring to `spring-session`. `HttpSecurity` allows you to configure `sessionManagement()`, which I believe will handle your use case.

Comment: A further requirement is that a user session created through a trusted partner site should not count towards this limit. Would HttpSecurity be configurable to handle that use case?

Comment: You could provide a custom `SessionRegistry` via `http.sessionManagement().sessionRegistry()` and implement `sessionRegistry.getAllSessions()` to return whatever sessions you see fit based on your requirements. I believe this would work for you. See the logic in `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` to understand how it currently works.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @JoeGrandja since my auth server is running on multiple instances, the session registry will need to be backed by external storage - can that be done without pulling in spring sessions?